# XSL functions with xsl param as parameters

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I will try to keep the terminology clear here, the overloading of terms is making this complicated.

I have a transform that I am passing an attribute to fill a xsl:param, this is working

```
<xsl:param name="platform"/>
```

This will print out if I use

```
<xsl:value-of select='$platform'/>
```

Instead of printing this attribute/param I need to pass it to a function.
I have tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(current(),'replaceMe','$platform')"/>
```

I receive the error

> Invalid replacement string in replace(): $ sign must be followed by digit 0-9

Is there a way I can pass the param into the function?
If so, how do I need to format it?

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(current(), 'replaceMe', $platform)" />
```

- `$platform` is a variable.
- `"$platform"` is an invalid replacement string in the context of the `replace()` function, which [works with regex](https://www.w3.org/2006/xpath-functions/#replace) and expects [back-refereces](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) like `$1` or `$2` in the replacement string when it sees `$`.

---

Logical conclusion: You will see the same error again as soon as the `$platform` variable accidentally contains a `$`, and another error when `'replaceMe'` accidentally is an invalid regular expression. If it happens to be a valid regular expression and you don't know it, you might see other unexpected behavior.

Therefore - if you want to do verbatim search-and-replace with variables - you must properly regex-escape all special characters in the search pattern and at least escape any `$` and `\` in the replacement string. A robust "verbatim" replace call looks like this:

```
replace(
  $subject,
  replace($searchString, '[.\[\]\\|^$?*+{}()-]','\\$0'),
  replace($replacement, '[\\$]', '\\$0')
)
```